# Linked List remove

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have this piece of code. It is syntactically correct, but when I am trying to remove a node from front it says "The list is Empty".
I believe that my mistake is in the `isEmpty` method, because it returns the wrong value, but I don't know why.

Could you please help me to detect why?

Here is my code:

```
public class link {
    public String bookName  ; 
    public  int millionSold; 

    public link next ;

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        linkList linkedlist = new linkList(); 
        linkedlist.insertLink("Head first java", 200);
        linkedlist.insertLink("Head first design pattern", 400);
        linkedlist.insertLink("Head first design", 600);
        linkedlist.display();
        System.out.println(linkedlist.isEmpty()); 
        linkedlist.findItem("Abed"); 
    }

    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println(bookName +":"+millionSold+"000.000"); 
    }

    public link(String bookName,int millionSold)
    {
        this.bookName=bookName; 
        this.millionSold=millionSold; 
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return bookName ; 
    }
}
```

Linklist

```
class linkList
{
    public link firstLink ;

    linkList()
    {
        firstLink = null ; 
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        boolean empty ; 
        if(firstLink==null)
        {
            empty = true ; 
        }
        else
        {
            empty = false ;
        }
        return empty; 
    }

    public void insertLink(String bookName , int millionSold)
    {
        link newLink = new link(bookName,millionSold);

        newLink.next = firstLink;
        firstLink=newLink ; 
    }
    public link removeLink()
    {
        link linkReference = firstLink ; 
        if(!isEmpty())
            linkReference.next= firstLink;
        else
            System.out.println("The List is Empty");

        return linkReference ; 
    }

    public void display()
    {
        while(firstLink!=null)
        {
            firstLink.display();
            System.out.println("The Next :"+firstLink.next);
            firstLink = firstLink.next; 
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

        public link findItem(String bookName)
        {   
            if(!isEmpty())
            {
                while(firstLink.bookName != bookName)
                {
                    if(firstLink.next == null)
                    {
                        return null ; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        firstLink=firstLink.next;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Can not find a match");
            }
            return firstLink ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is provided above , just scroll down to see the whole code please

Comment: It probably has something to do with the fact that you modify your `firstLink` field in some methods that in my humble opinion have no business modifying the state of your list (`display` and `findItem`)

Answer (score 0):

In the `removeLink` the assignment `linkReference.next= firstLink;` assigned `firstLink` to `linkReference.next` where infact you want the other way round. You want `firstLink` to be `linkReference.next` so try changing `firstLink=linkReference.next;`

Another observation is in `display` and `findItem` do not use `firstLink` as you changing the pointer to your list (your only entry-point) as you run the method.

Comment: it gave the same result , check isEmpty method 
mistake is there but i can not figure it out

Comment: did you update the `display` and `findItem` method as well as explained in the answer?

Comment: it worked when updated as you mentioned above.
another question here i have updated but i have misunderstanding
when i have to use a temp value for the firstlink in each time i want to use it among these methods ?

Comment: @sosoqurashi You have to use a temporary variable when you don't want your actual firstLink to change. Your firstLink field of your list is a reference to the actual first Element of your list. So think about it like that: If you want to display your current list, should that change the first element of that list or the list at all? Obviously no, you just want to display the list without changing it, so you should not modify any fields of your list.

Comment: `firstLink` is a pointer to the list, you change `firstLink` only if you change the first element of the list. During `display` and `find` since you are not changing your list then you cannot change `firstLink`

Answer (score 0):

Use temp variable (`cursor` below) to navigate through your list. Otherwise you're defining null to firstLink and it seems like list is empty.

```
public void display()
{
    link cursor = firstLink;
    while(cursor!=null)
    {
        cursor.display();
        System.out.println("The Next :"+cursor.next);
        cursor = cursor.next; 
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

and doing the same where you want to loop through list ( ex. `findItem()`) will be better approach.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your display() method. You iterate through the list and after that the *firstLink* variable becomes null. You need to add a temporary variable just for iteration in the display() method, like:

```
link tempLink = firstLink;
while (tempLink != null) {
    tempLink.display();
    System.out.println("The Next: " + firstLink.next);
    tempLink = tempLink.next;
    System.out.println();
}
```

Use the same technique in other places where you iterate through the list but don't want to change a head (e.g. findItem() method).

I would also recommend capitalize name of all classes in Java. You can read more about Java naming conventios [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).